# Lipschitz maximal inequality for random process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, packing-and-covering, random-functions

I am confused on [the Lemma 5.7 (Lipschitz maximal inequality) here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ervan/APC550.pdf). Let me first restate the definition and the lemma:

**Def**
$\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ is called Lipschitz for metric $d$ on $T$ if there exists a random variable $C$ such that
$$|X_t-X_s|\leq Cd(t,s),\text{ for all }t,s\in T.$$

**Lemma**
Suppose $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ is a Lipschitz process and is $\sigma^2$-subgaussian for every $T$. Then $$E[\sup_{t\in T}X_t]\leq \inf_{\epsilon>0}\{\epsilon E[C]+\sqrt{2\sigma^2\log N(T,d,\epsilon)}$$

To prove the lemma, we split $X_t$ into two parts, i.e. $$\sup_{t\in T}X_t\leq \sup_{t\in T}\{X_t-X_{\pi(t)}\}+\sup_{t\in T}X_{\pi(t)}$$ then take expectation we have $$E[\sup_{t\in T}X_t]\leq \epsilon E[C]+\sqrt{2\sigma^2\log|N|}$$

I am a bit confused on the applicability of this lemma on random process that its $E[\sup X_t]$ is negative.

In the proof, we use the Lipschitz bound to control $\sup_{t\in T}\{X_t-X_{\pi(t)}\}\leq Cd(t,\pi(t))$. Clearly, this bound $Cd(t,\pi(t))$ is non-negative, thus the the resulting bound $ \inf_{\epsilon>0}\{\epsilon E[C]+\sqrt{2\sigma^2\log N(T,d,\epsilon)}$ in the lemma is also non-negative.

But, what if the expectation of sup of random process is negative? Then the bound given by the lemma is very loose.

For example, I guess this process $\sum_{i=1}^n(-100+w_i)\sin(\theta_i)$ where $w_i$ is iid standard gaussian would have negative expectation of supreme.

Am I misunderstood something on this lemma?

Comment: $\sup |X_{s}|\leq \sup_{s,t} |X_{s}-X_{t}|+|X_{t_{0}}|$

Comment: in the case of a Gaussian process, you can just use symmetry $w=-w$ to get absolute value ie $P(\sup |w_{t}|>r)\leq 2P(\sup w_{t}>r)$.

Comment: The Lemma in question is stated for centered random variables, so the expectation of the supremum is always nonnegative.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks! by using $\sup |X_s|\leq \sup_{s,t}|X_s-X_t|+\sup_tX_t$ we can only get information on $\sup |X_s|$ right? Then how can we know about $\sup X_s$?

Comment: I didn't write $sup_{t}X_{t}$.  I fixed $t_{0}$ because usually in a stochastic process the pointwise tail estimate is known (otherwise we can't even use chaining to estimate the supremum). I simply bounded $|X_{s}|\leq |X_{s}-X_{t_{0}}|+|X_{t_{0}}|$ and then took supremum over only the first one (which might be unnecessary). For the first you have a bound by $zero$ (and you can use modulus estimates).

Comment: ah ok. if I understood correctly: the goal is to derive bound on $\sup |X_s|$, am I correct? but then how does this relate to $\sup X_s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\td{\tilde d}$You wrote: "I am a bit confused on the applicability of this lemma on random process that its $E[\sup X_t]$ is negative."

One way to use this result, whether $E\sup_{t\in T} X_t$ is negative or not, is as follows. We have

> $$E\sup_{t\in T}X_t\le \inf_{\ep>0}\big\{\ep EC+\sqrt{2\si^2\ln N(T,d,\ep)}\big\} \tag{10}\label{10} $$
> given that
> $$|X_t-X_s|\le Cd(t,s)\text{ for all }(t,s)\in T\times T. \tag{20}\label{20}$$

Here $N(T,d,\ep)$ is the smallest number of balls of radius $\ep$ in metric $d$ needed to cover the set $T$, and $C>0$ is a random variable.

By appropriately truncating the $X_t$'s and $d$ (or by going through the proof of this highlighted result), here we may allow $d$ to be a generalized metric -- such that $d(t,s)$ may take the value $\infty$ for some $(t,s)\in T\times T$.

Let a set $S$ be a copy of the set $T$ **disjoint** from $T$, so that we have a bijection $f$ from $S$ onto $T$. For all $u\in U:=T\cup S$, let
$$Y_u:=\begin{cases}
X_u&\text{ if }u\in T, \\
-X_{f(u)}&\text{ if }u\in S.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$\sup_{u\in U}Y_u=\max\Big(\sup_{u\in T}X_u,\sup_{u\in S}(-X_{f(u)})\Big) \\ 
=\max\Big(\sup_{t\in T}X_t,\sup_{t\in T}(-X_t)\Big)
=\sup_{t\in T}|X_t|. \tag{30}\label{30}
$$
Extend the generalized metric $d$ on $T\times T$ to the generalized metric $\td$ on $U\times U$ by the formula
$$\td(u,v):=\begin{cases}
d(u,v)&\text{ if }(u,v)\in T\times T, \\
d(f(u),f(v))&\text{ if }(u,v)\in S\times S, \\
\infty&\text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $|Y_u-Y_v|\le C\td(u,v)\text{ for all }(u,v)\in U\times U$; cf. \eqref{20}. So, by the highlighted result,
$$E\sup_{u\in U}Y_u\le \inf_{\ep>0}\big\{\ep EC+\sqrt{2\si^2\ln N(U,\td,\ep)}\big\}. \tag{40}\label{40}$$

But $N(U,\td,\ep)\le2N(T,d,\ep)$ for real $\ep>0$.
So, by \eqref{30} and \eqref{40},
$$E\sup_{t\in T}|X_t|\le \inf_{\ep>0}\big\{\ep EC+\sqrt{2\si^2\ln (2N(T,d,\ep))}\big\}. $$

Comment: thanks for your answer! how does $E\sup|X_t|$ relate to $E\sup X_t$?

Comment: for example, for any $t\in T$, $X_t<0$. Then $\sup X_t<0$, thus $E\sup X_t<0$ as well. Since $E\sup|X_t|=E\sup(-X_t)=E(-\inf X_t)$, if we know the upper bound of $E\sup|X_t|\leq\cdots$ (as derived in your answer), then we know the lower bound if $E(\inf X_t)\geq\cdots$. But our goal is to obtain the upper bound of $E(\sup X_t)\leq\cdots$, equivalently $E(-\inf -X_t)\leq\cdots$, and equivalently $E(\inf -X_t)\geq\cdots$.

Comment: @chloe :  "how does $E\sup_{t\in T}|X_t|$ relate to $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t$?" -- One such relation is $|E\sup_{t\in T}X_t|\le E\sup_{t\in T}|X_t|$. However, the question in your post was not how $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t$ relates to other things. The question was not, either, "to obtain the upper bound on $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t$" (and actually what could the "the" in "the upper bound" possibly refer to?). Rather, your posted question was "on the applicability of this lemma on random process that its $E[\sup X_t]$ is negative".

Comment: Previous comment continued: Of course, the lemma is **trivially** applicable to $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t$ even when $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t<0$ -- in the sense that the lemma does provide an upper bound on $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t$, even if the bound would be trivial when $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t<0$. My answer provides a less trivial application of the lemma. Also, I have to say that, in typical applications of this lemma, $X_t$ would be zero-mean for all $t$, and then $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t\ge\sup_{t\in T}EX_t=0$, so that $E\sup_{t\in T}X_t\ge0$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: If the research you are working on is not of this typical kind, then perhaps indeed this lemma is not useful to you, and you should look for other tools.